# Best practices for publishing apps for G-Suite users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace

What account(s) should I use to publish a HTMLService-based Web App for use by the entire 50-user G-Suite organization which has 3 admins?  I'm considering these options:

1. Dedicated account "AppPublisher@_our_domain.com". Password in a Google Doc file which all 3 admins have access to.
2. One of the admins is the Script Project owner, others are editors.  Any admin can publish and republish as needed.

Both have pros and cons.  When using dedicated account, it's easier to manage access to the resources the script requires, but sharing a password doesn't seem ideal.  On another hand, (2) seems to be prone to a long-standing bug where publish dialog gets stuck on "Fetching data..."/spinning wheel forever.

Is there another option I'm not seeing?  Thanks!

Comment: Your question may be better for [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)  If you post your question there, and then post the link in the comment section here, someone may respond.

Comment: This looks like an primarily opinion-based question.